# How to invert the Progress-Label when it is overlaping with the bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

so I got this code at work and was asked to find a way to improve it. We are using a HTML5 progress element which contains a separate label.

The label gets placed over the progress-bar by using

```
margin-top: -40px;
```

since the progress-bar has a fixed height.

I made a jsfiddle for you so you can see how the progress-element is implemented.

https://jsfiddle.net/o3y6zxdx/

Now i want to edit the code in a way that the part of the label, which is covered by the progress-bar, changes its color. In the fiddle above "Loadi" should be displayed white.

Since i am new to coding i have some problems with this task, so is there any way to realize this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want with just the `progress` element, you need to use JavaScript and 2 labels, which may not be the most efficient method.

A solution that doesn't require JavaScript is to make your progress bar out of `div`s instead of using the `progress` element. The inner `div` has white text, and the outer `div` has black text. When the `divs` are overlapped to create a progress bar, the white text will be cut off at 56%, showing the rest of the black text from behind.

```css
#bar {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}
#progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 56%;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.progress-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
}
.full-width {
  width: 300px; // set the desired width of your progress bar
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bar" class="progress-bar full-width">
      <div class="text full-width">
        Loading...56%
      </div>
      <div id="progress" class="progress-bar">
        <div class="text full-width">
          Loading...56%
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tnkswtw3/18/